# Cocos2d and iOS: Can't understand use of control points using ccBezierConfig 

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, uibezierpath

EDIT: If the question is badly written have a look at the video ([3](http://youtu.be/IQ_Jf0O0KGc)), same link as in the bottom of this page.

I am trying to draw a very simple bezier curve using **ccBezierConfig** and Cocos2D. Reading on Wikipedia I tried to understand a bit controls points and found this image:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Bezier_2_big.png/240px-Bezier_2_big.png

If you look on the wikipedia page from which I took the image there is a cool animation. Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezier_curve).

This is the code I used:

```
        CCSprite *r = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"hi.png"];
        r.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);
        r.position = CGPointMake(0.0f, 200.0f);

        ccBezierConfig bezier;
        bezier.controlPoint_1 = CGPointMake(0.0f, 200.0f);
        bezier.controlPoint_1 = CGPointMake(180.0f, 330.0f);
        bezier.endPosition = CGPointMake(320.0f,200.0f);

        id bezierForward = [CCBezierBy actionWithDuration:1 bezier:bezier];
        [r runAction:bezierForward];
        [self addChild:r z:0 tag:77];
```

The app runs on Portrait mode and my speculation matching the control points of [1](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Bezier_2_big.png/240px-Bezier_2_big.png) and the ones in my code was that:

```
sprite.position should correspond to P0
bezier.controlPoint_1 should correspond to P0 
bezier.controlPoint_2 should correspond to P1
bezier.endPosition  should correspond to P2
```

I did try two approaches. By setting the position of the sprite and by not setting it.

I assumed that position should be the same as controlPoint_1 as in the wikipedia schema [1](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Bezier_2_big.png/240px-Bezier_2_big.png) there are only three points.

**I get an output I don't quiet understand.. I made a little video of it, is a private youtube video:**

**[to see the video click here](http://youtu.be/IQ_Jf0O0KGc)**

Comment: btw, you seem to have a typo there, you are assigning `controlPoint_1` twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the answer is rather simple...

The **[quadratic Bézier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Quadratic_curves)** is not the one drawn by cocos2d. Instead, check the same wiki page for **[cubic Bézier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Higher-order_curves)**. That's what you should be looking at.

1. Initial position is the position of the sprite (P0)
2. Control points 1 & 2 are P1 & P2, respectively.
3. End point is the end point.

Nice video, btw, I enjoyed it xD.

---

Evidence from the `CCActionInterval.h` file in the cocos2d library:

```
/** An action that moves the target with a cubic Bezier curve by a certain distance.
 */
@interface CCBezierBy : CCActionInterval <NSCopying>
{
    ccBezierConfig config;
    CGPoint startPosition;
}
```

---

[This link](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~lambert/splines/Bezier.html) should help you construct your **[cubic Bézier curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Higher-order_curves)** visually, instead of tweaking the values and running the app.

Comment: Link is dead or I get a 403 :-(