# Cocos2d 2.x: understanding ccBezierConfig beheaviour

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, bezier

I am on this since a while and time ago I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430651/cocos2d-and-ios-cant-understand-use-of-control-points-using-ccbezierconfig) and a user kindly replied to me explaning that there is [this plugin tool](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~lambert/splines/Bezier.html) that I can use to create quick bezier curves prototypes.

I tried and produced this:

[image: That's what I produced with the tool]

I **thought** it would be perfectly translated in this ccBezierConfig:

```
ccBezierConfig bezier;
self.position = CGPointMake(-10.0f, 400.0f);
bezier.controlPoint_1 = CGPointMake(160, 190.0f);
bezier.controlPoint_2 = CGPointMake(200, 190.0f);
bezier.endPosition =CGPointMake(340.0f,280.0f);

id bezierForward = [CCBezierBy actionWithDuration:3 bezier:bezier];    
[self runAction: [CCSequence actions:
                  bezierForward, [CCHide action],
                  nil]];
```

Unfortunately the path I get is not quiet what I was expecting. The character starts to move from the top left corner of the screen and then just goes up and I don't see the movement I expected.

Any explanation on what am I doing wrong?

Btw.. I am using Cocos2d 2.0 on iOS 6.0, retina display iPod touch 4th generation.

EDIT:

Another example..

I thought that this configuration would do like in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bezier_3_big.png)   and then do the symmetric thing from the end to the start but "upside down".

Any suggestions on what am I doing wrong?

```
    ccBezierConfig bezier;

     self.position = CGPointMake(0.0f, 150.0f);
     bezier.controlPoint_1 = CGPointMake(-20.0f, 290.0f);
     bezier.controlPoint_2 = CGPointMake(260, 290.0f);
     bezier.endPosition =CGPointMake(340.0f,150.0f);

    id bezierForward = [CCBezierBy actionWithDuration:3 bezier:bezier];


    ccBezierConfig bezier2;
    bezier2.controlPoint_1 = CGPointMake(340.0f, 10.0f);
    bezier2.controlPoint_2 = CGPointMake(80, 10.0f);
    bezier2.endPosition =CGPointMake(-20.0f,150.0f);

    id bezierReturn = [CCBezierBy actionWithDuration:3 bezier:bezier2];


    [self runAction: [CCSequence actions:
                      bezierForward, bezierReturn, [CCHide action],
                      nil]];
```

Comment: That link to the site with the bezier app made out of java... well, my browser blocks the hell out that java stuff. Anyone know another site NOT using anything dangerous? html5 anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using CCBezierBy but the examples are based on a CCBezierTo formula. Hence everything works as excpected if I use CCBezierTo instaed of CCBezierBy.